# how to get the type of argument in variable argument using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, variables, arguments

I have a method with variable arguments, the argument may be int, NSString or other classes.I want handle each argument rely on one's type.So I am trying to get the type of each argument, but I failed.
Here is my code :

.h file

```
-(void)handleArgs:(NSString *)firstArg, ...;
```

.m file

```
-(void)handleArgs:(NSString *)firstArg, ...
{
   va_list argList;
   va_start(argList, firstArg);
   // get each object and get its type and handle it by type
   va_end(argList);
}
```

I will call it like this :

```
NSArray *list = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item1", @"item2", @"item3", nil];
[self handleArgs:@"test", 100, @"arg2", list, nil];
```

So how to implement this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Varargs does not preserve type information. You will either need to have the first argument provide type information for the rest (like printf does) or you will have to make all the arguments compatible types. (It is possible to have arguments of different object types, though, since all objects share the static type `id`.)